# I got a scholarship to college

Tags: single-word-requests

Why do people say

> get a scholarship **to** college

instead of

> get a scholarship **from** college

Doesn't the money come *from* the college?

Comment: No, the scholarship doesn't necessarily come from the college/university. It can come from a third party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, unnecessary** words are often omitted.  In this case, what is really being said is:

> I got a scholarship [*to go*] to college.

The scholarship might come from the college itself or it might come from somewhere else such as a labor union, a fraternal organization, an employer, or a club.

My son, who has very expensive tastes in colleges, is hoping to get scholarships from my wife's union, the robotics organization he's a part of, and so on.

**note that *unnecessary* is very much subjective; what one person feels is unnecessary information might be considered critical by another.